# Finding the tension in two ropes.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have a problem that says to find the tension in two ropes in the following figure.

[image]

The answers are `1830kg` in the right rope and `2241kg` in the left rope. I'm able to successfully solve the tension in the right rope, but I keep getting `1294kg` for the left rope.

Here is how I'm doing it:

v = tension in right rope

u = tension in left rope

Equation 1: $v*cos(60) - u*cos(45) = 0$

Equation 2: $v*sin(60) + u*sin(45) - 2500kg = 0$

Then, from Equation 1, solve for u:

$u = \frac{v*cos(60)}{cos(45)}$

And plug this in to Equation 2 and solve for v:

$v = \frac{2500}{sin(60) + tan(45)*cos(60)} = 1830 kg$

Now that I have v, I use it in Equation 1 to solve u

$u = \frac{1830kg*cos(60)}{cos(45)} = 1294kg$

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You don't measure tension in kilograms.  The value of $g$ needs to be in there somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $30^\circ$ is the complement of $60^\circ$
$$u = \frac{1830kg\cdot\cos(30^\circ)}{\cos(45^\circ)} = 2241.283kg$$

Comment: Oh I see now! Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that you have incorrectly chosen the sine and cosine functions. Only the fact that one angle is $45^\circ$ degrees allows you to get one of the forces right, since $\sin(45^\circ)=\cos(45^\circ)$

There are several ways to prevent this error.  Here's one

Consider your first equation:

> v∗cos(60)−u∗cos(45)=0

This equation correctly **attempts** to set the net horizontal force equal to zero.

Now ask yourself:  what would happen to the **horizontal** component of the right force if the $60^\circ$ angle were to increase to nearly $90^\circ$?  Clearly, the horizontal component would increase to a maximum.  **But you used the cosine function, which decreases to zero for a  $90^\circ$ angle!**  Clearly, you are in trouble.

Similarly. in your second equation you are attempting to set the total of all **vertical** components to zero:

> v∗sin(60)+u∗sin(45)−2500kg=0

If the $60^\circ$ angle increased to $90^\circ$, the **vertical** component would disappear, but **your equation uses the $\sin$ function, which reaches a maximum for $90^\circ$**

Doing this sort of reality check gives you the chance to reverse the two functions and get the correct result.